# How do I use JavaScript regex to search for everything except for one instance?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using JavaScript regex and would like to strip HTML tags out of a string except for one situation.

Let's take this string for example:

```
"<a>link me</a> 
 <p class="highlight">paragraph</p> 
 <replace meta="data"></replace>"
```

I would like to use string replace to transform it into:
(all HTML tags are stripped except for `<[/?]replace[.*]>`)

`"link me paragraph <replace meta="data"></replace>"`

The regex for removing all tags would be:

```
html = String(html).replace(/<[^>]+>/gm, '');
```

How would one go about placing the exception for `<replace>` and `</replace>` in there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use negative lookahead:

```
/(?!<\/?replace)<[^>]+>/gm
```

The `(?!<\/?replace)` negative lookahead asserts that `<[^>]+>` cannot match if it's a replace opening or closing tag.

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/xE5dR7/2)

```js
var str = `<a>link me</a>
 <p class="highlight">paragraph</p>
 <replace meta="data">DO NOT REPLACE</replace>`;

var re = /(?!<\/?replace)<[^>]+>/gm;

document.querySelector('pre').textContent = str.replace(re, '');
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

The classic approach is to first match **and capture** what you want to keep (in this case, the `<replace>` tags), then as an alternative match everything else you don't want to keep (in this case, all other tags), then replace what matched with the captured content, which will have the effect of throwing away the unwanted tags:

```js
var string = `<a>link me</a> 
 <p class="highlight">paragraph</p> 
 <replace meta="data"></replace>`;

var re = /(<\/?replace.*?>)|<.*?>/g;
//        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^             CAPTURE WHAT WE WANT TO KEEP
//                          ^^^^^       DON'T CAPTURE WHAT WE DON'T WANT TO KEEP

var result = string.replace(re, '$1');
//                              ^^^^    REPLACE WITH CAPTURE

document.getElementById('result').textContent = result;
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Negative look-ahead also is a fine solution, but some might consider this approach a bit more straightforward.